# Problemas com ajax no servidor

Tags: ajax, apache, zend-framework-2

Tenho uma aplicação em `ZF2` em servidor Ubuntu. Um dos controllers é acionado a partir de uma requisição `ajax`.

Localmente, a aplicação funciona normalmente. Contudo, ao subir para o servidor comecei a ter problemas: a requisição é enviada como POST, mas não consigo pegar os dados no controlador, pois lá chega como GET e com o array de dados vazio.

Alguém saberia qual o problema, já que o mesmo código funciona em ambiente local?

No `controller` o `get` dos dados:

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray();
            $request = $this->request;
            $post = array_merge_recursive(
                    $request->getPost()->toArray(), $request->getFiles()->toArray()
            );
            $postData = array();
            $error = array();
            $errSuccess = array();

            //get Query String
            parse_str($post['data'], $postData);
```

No html tenho o seguinte código:

```
wizard.on("submit", function (wizard) {

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('upload', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);

            var ins = document.getElementById('gallery').files.length;
            for (var x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
                formData.append('gallery[]', $('input[type=file]')[1].files[x]);

            }

            formData.append('data', wizard.serialize());

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/advertiser/add',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (resp) {
                    if (resp.response == 1) {
                        $(".create-server-name").text($("#nome_razao").val());
                        wizard.submitSuccess();
                        wizard.hideButtons();
                        wizard.updateProgressBar(0);
                        $.each(wizard.cards, function (name, card) {
                            card.el.find("input").val(); // resets all inputs on a card to ""
                        });
                    } else if (resp.response == 2) {
                        var str = '';
                        for (obj in resp.result) {
                            str += "<li>" + resp.result[obj] + "</li>";
                        }
                        $(".create-server-name").text($("#nome_razao").val());
                        $('#errmsg').html(str);
                        console.log(str);
                        wizard.submitSuccess();
                        wizard.hideButtons();
                        wizard.updateProgressBar(0)
                        $.each(wizard.cards, function (name, card) {
                            card.el.find("input").val(); // resets all inputs on a card to ""
                        });
                    } else {
                        var str = '';

                        $('#errmsgerr').html(resp.result);
                        console.log(str);
                        wizard.submitError();
                        wizard.hideButtons();
                        wizard.updateProgressBar(0)
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    wizard.submitFailure();
                    wizard.hideButtons();
                },
            });

        });
```

O php.ini não foi alterado após a instalação. Versão php:

```
PHP 5.6.23-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Este é o .htaccess, que é o mesmo para os 2 ambientes:

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Fran, Vejo que você está tendo fazer upload de arquivos. Minha sugestão é você usar algo pronto. Tem um plugin muito bom para upload de arquivos, veja se isso pode ajudar. http://www.dropzonejs.com

Comment: O próprio template que uso force algo similar ao Dorpzone.

Comment: Quais a versão do PHP no local e no servidor? Coloque as configurações do php.ini relevantes por favor.

Comment: O php.ini não foi alterado após a instalação do php

Comment: Verifique a diretiva: `enable_post_data_reading` do php.ini de seu servidor